# ArcGIS: How to programmatically refresh selected features

Tags: arcobjects, c#

**Background:** I have C#, ArcGIS command that 1. lists selected features, and 2. allows you to delete selected features from this list out of a geodatabase.

**My problem:** After I delete features, ArcGIS doesn't update the selected features list.  When my program asks ArcGIS for the selected features, it gets back references to the features it already deleted.  It shouldn't.

**My Question**: What should I do to tell ArcGIS to check the selected features list for non-existent features?  Is there a "refresh" command that will do this, or do I have to reselect the features (excluding the deleted ones) programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in ArcMap? How exactly are you deleting features from the geodatabase? When you use `IEditor` to do those edits, changes to selection when deleting features should propagate properly.

You might also try casting the [Map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/MapClass_Class/001200000s13000000/) to [ISelectionEvents](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ISelectionEvents_Interface/001200000qn6000000/) and calling [SelectionChanged](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/SelectionChanged_Event/001200000qn7000000/) to notify of selection change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your good questions.  I am in ArcMap. The query is being done via a database connection (OleDbConnection), rather than using IEditor.  I would fix it to use IEditor but it would involve a lot of rewiring. I will try your proposed solution.

Comment: SelectionChanged didn't work for me. What I ultimately did was call Refresh on the SelectionSet object.  I'm accepting your answer because it got me on track to a solution.